# VS code debug console not working

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have installed VS Code 1.9.1 version.i am debugging typescript file but i could not do it always when i clicking start Debugging button i am getting this message:Cannot launch program 'c:\xampp\htdocs\typescriptproj.vscode\launch.json'; setting the 'outFiles' attribute might help.
How to resolve this issue.

My Folder Structure:

typescriptproj->foldername

```
        -script.js
        -script.ts
```

.vscode

```
       -launch.json
       -settings.josn ->empty
```

```js
script.ts
//String
let valstring:string;
valstring="sankars";

console.log(valstring);


launch.json:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "outFiles": []
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "port": 5858,
            "outFiles": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
"outFiles": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/**/*.js"
        ],
```

VS-code runs js code, not ts code. So you should specify where the VS-code should look for js code.